# How can I iterate over all visible html elements and hide them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently writing a website using Three.js. At the top of my website I had a navbar. One requirement I am needing is that when I click on a different navbar page, I need to iterate over all of the currently visible html elements and hide them, excluding the nav bar. So the structure is currently like this.

```
<div class="website container">
    <nav> 
    .... 

    </nav>
    <div ...
</div>
```

I want to have something like this,

```
for (html_element of all_html_elements_excluding_excluding_nav) {
     html_element.hide()
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Wrap everything else to an element, and hide that element, no need to check if something is visible.

Comment: @Teemu I began the implementation of your idea, but I later ran into the problem. The issue is that I have all html elements on the page, some hidden and others not. The issue is that I use gsap to create a fade effect where I set the opacity from 1 -> 0 over 1 second. However if I set the container element to a fade from opacity 1 -> 0, then it will set items all html elements initially visible, including those that were not. So I need to grab only the current visible ones.

Comment: @Joe I'd really like to see an example of your problem.